# Tell if PC comes out of standby using Qt

Tags: c++, python, qt

Is there a cross platform way, using Qt, to tell if a computer has come out of standby or hibernation.

I need to be able to detect when the computer has come out of standby in order to reset/continue a process.  In this case it is a connection to a GPS via serial port.

Comment: I don't know a direct way, but how about setting up a QTimer to fire every second, and each time it fires, record the current time and compare it to the time it fired previously.  If the difference is much greater than 1 second, then presumably the computer was asleep and that's why the slot didn't get called "on schedule".

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner That's a creative solution.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Good solution! But don't use the system time - the user can change that at will, causing spurious trips. (KDE's `kwin` has this problem.) Instead, since you have a GPS unit handy, use the GPS time instead.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: " If the difference is much greater than 1 second, then presumably" Nope, this is a bad idea. Then presumably something hogged CPU or tried allocating 15 gigabytes of RAM in small chunks, and the system was REALLY busy to send you timer message. 1-second system-wide "hiccup" isn't that uncommon on both linux and windows. However, if you increase the delay (to say, 1 minute), then your app might miss situation when computer was hibernated for less than a minute.

Comment: @Sigterm: good point. Perhaps the best thing to check is simply "is the GPS connection active?"

Comment: If you would like to see this functionality in Qt, vote for [QTBUG-96637](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-96637)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion at http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/39649 it seems that there is no reliable cross-platform way of doing this. The linked discussion provides some instructions on how to do this on windows and mac by listening to platform signaling.